# How do I set the fringe colors to whatever is the background color?

Tags: fringe, colors

I am using a distraction-free mode that uses giant fringes to center the buffer called [`bzg-big-fringe-mode`](https://gist.github.com/bzg/8578998).

Problem is, these fringes often have a different color than the background which give an ugly visual effect (see the picture at the end).

I do not have a problem with fixing this manually, by setting the fringe color to the background color, like so:

`(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "#3F3F3F" :foreground "#3F3F3F")`

Problem is, when changing themes the fringe colors remain gray, even though that does not make sense for the new theme.

Is there a way to programmatically set the fringe to the background color?

I guess I need two things:

1. The ability to set the fringe background color to the default
   background color.
2. A function that is hooked to changing themes
   and that does 1. above.

I think I should be able to do 2) even though I have no emacs skills, but how do I do 1)?

Or is this a bad idea for some reason? If so, what would a better approach look like?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The official way would be customizing the theme in question to make the fringe face look the same as the background face. A face spec along the lines of `(fringe :inherit default)` should do the trick.

Alternatively, you can modify it on the fly using a code snippet:

```
(defun my-tone-down-fringes ()
  (set-face-attribute 'fringe nil
                      :foreground (face-foreground 'default)
                      :background (face-background 'default)))
```

The only problem left would be applying it on every theme change. I can't find any hook looking like it could do the job which is a bit sad, `defadvice` doesn't seem to work out properly either. At least not in Emacs 24.4

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait till Monday with accepting in case sb has a solution.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use [`face-background`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-face_002dbackground-3886) and `face-foreground` in this code snippet?

Comment: There isn't, edited.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the fringe color to nil, in which case you don't need to worry about any theme changes. I've got the following in my config:

`(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background nil)`

And the fringe just disappears.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `'fringe` stopped working for me, and now this does:

```
(set-face-attribute 'linum nil :background "gray19")
```